# SQL to select employees those who have DOB for the day

Tags: oracle, mysqli

I'm new to SQL,

I have field called DOB with 2014-11-07 00:00:00.0 date format in my Database.
I just wanted to select the records which has DOB equal to current date.

I want this to select employees who have DOB for the current day.

Regards 
Shridhar

Comment: did you try writing some code?

Comment: Which DB server is actually in question here? Is it Oracle? Or is it MySQL? What is the `mysqli` tag ("The mysqli PHP extension") actually doing in your question alongside the "oracle" tag ("Oracle Server is an Object-relational Database Management System")?

Comment: Your company must be pretty keen if it is already employing someone who was only just born today :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below query worked fine for me.

SELECT * FROM $A$ WHERE TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(DOB,'MMDD'),'MMDD') =trunc(sysdate)

Regards 
Shridhar

Comment: $A$ is table table name.

Answer (score 1):

In `Oracle` you can do this:

```
select * from employees e where trunc(e.DOB) =  trunc(sysdate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming this is MySQl or Oracle
If you have a table called Employees, you should be able do use this.

```
SELECT A.*
  FROM EMPLOYEES A
 WHERE DATE(A.DOB) = CURDATE();
```

Here is a resource to learn all about different date functions used in MySQL and Oracle:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/date-and-time-functions.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-date

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged `MySQL`. You can use [`EXTRACT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract) function to get the day of the specific date in [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql)

```
select * from employee
where extract(day,DOB) = extract(day, now());
```

Comment: But (on Oracle 11.2) `SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM (TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-11-07 00:00:00.0', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF1'))) FROM DUAL;` does return just `7`…

Comment: @Abecee, this answer is meant for MySQL as OP tagged. Let me clear that in answer.